# DRBD Setup on 2 node CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, drbd

I have installed and configured DRBD on 2 centos nodes and after creating the metadata when i try to start the drbd service, its complaining that the module is not loaded. See below for more details. Any help is appreciated.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# service drbd status
drbd not loaded

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# drbdadm up clusterdb
Could not stat("/proc/drbd"): No such file or directory
do you need to load the module?
try: modprobe drbd
Command 'drbdsetup 0 disk /dev/sda3 /dev/sda3 internal --set-defaults --create-device' terminated with exit code 20
drbdadm attach clusterdb: exited with code 20

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# modprobe drbd
FATAL: Module drbd not found.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# service drbd start

Starting DRBD resources: Can not load the drbd module.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# uname -a
Linux nfs-node1 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep drbd
kmod-drbd83-8.3.16-3.el6.elrepo.x86_64
drbd83-utils-8.3.16-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]#

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

DRBD Configuration:

resource clusterdb
{
startup {
wfc-timeout 30;
outdated-wfc-timeout 20;
degr-wfc-timeout 30;
}
net {
cram-hmac-alg sha1;
shared-secret sync_disk;
}
syncer {
rate 10M;
al-extents 257;
on-no-data-accessible io-error;
}
on nfs-node1 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/sda3;
address 192.168.1.1:7788;
flexible-meta-disk internal;
}
on nfs-node2 {
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/sda3;
address 192.168.1.2:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}
}

I have done this setup before without any problems. The only thing i'm doing differently here is that there is no network connection between the two nodes yet. I wanted to finish off the configurations first before i make the connections.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `drbd` module in your kernel. That is most likely a separate module in your CentOS package manager. So you need to find the kernel module and install it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did a yum search on that earlier and tried installing the module but it says its already installed and latest.

Comment: [root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# yum search drbd | grep kmod-drbd83
kmod-drbd83.x86_64 : drbd83 kernel module(s)
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# yum install -y kmod-drbd83.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: muug.ca
Package kmod-drbd83-8.3.16-3.el6.elrepo.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]#

Comment: anything else you can think of or can point me to the right place and right module where i can install from? Thank you!

Comment: I removed the drbd83 and installed drbd84 now but no luck. Still seeing the same error.

Comment: Installed:
  kmod-drbd84.x86_64 0:8.4.7-1_1.el6.elrepo

Dependency Installed:
  drbd84-utils.x86_64 0:8.9.5-1.el6.elrepo

Complete!
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]#
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep drbd
kmod-drbd84-8.4.7-1_1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
drbd84-utils-8.9.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# modprobe drbd
FATAL: Module drbd not found.
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# service drbd start
Can not load the drbd module.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# kmod-drbd84.x86_64

Comment: Try running `depmod -a`, which will update the module list used by `modprobe`. The package manager should run that, but better to double-check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no luck.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# depmod -a
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# service drbd start
Can not load the drbd module.

[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# modprobe drbd
FATAL: Module drbd not found.
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]# service drbd status
drbd not loaded
[root@nfs-node1 yum.repos.d]#

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load de module by using modprobe?

## modprobe drbd

and adding it to the modules loaded at boot
echo drbd > /etc/modules-load.d/drbd.conf